# Rotate shapes when clicking on on circle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on a circle, another shape should rotate, but there is something wrong with my loop. Here's my code:

```js
var Degree = 0;

function RotateDiv(obj) {
  let arak = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

  for (let i in arak) {
    Degree += 10
    arak[i].style.rotate = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="RotateDiv(this)" class="button">rotate</div>
<div class="s1"></div>
<div class="s2"></div>
<div class="s3"></div>
<div class="s4"></div>
```

It only works the first time. I get this message in the debugger:

```
 Paused on exception
ReferenceError: deg is not defined
```

Comment: Well you haven't defined `deg`. Try replacing it with `Degree`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ReferenceError: deg is not defined

Because of you don't have `deg` replaced with `Degree`

to rotate a `div` we have to use `transform = 'rotate(' + Degree + 'deg)'`

if you want all div to rotate same deg you have to move the `Degree += 10` to top of `forEach`

```js
var Degree = 0;

function RotateDiv(obj) {
  let arak = document.querySelectorAll(".example")

  arak.forEach((i) => {
    Degree += 10
    i.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Degree + 'deg)';
  })
}
```

```css
.example {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div onclick="RotateDiv(this)" class="button">rotate</div>
<div class="example s1"></div>
<div class="example s2"></div>
<div class="example s3"></div>
<div class="example s4"></div>
```